# Error when manually instantiating a template

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, clang

Recently at my company we ran into an error that I am having trouble understanding why it's actually an error. To us it seems as though this should compile just fine and allow us to explicitly instantiate a template of type bar::foo.

**mainy.cxx**

```
int foo(int);
namespace bar {
  template <typename T> T foo(T a, T){return a;}
}

namespace bar {
  using ::foo;
}

template int bar::foo(int, int);

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

**g++ error**

```
[csteifel@host:~/test]1047 $ g++ mainy.cxx
mainy.cxx:10: error: 'int bar::foo(int, int)' should have been declared inside 'bar'
mainy.cxx:10: error: 'int bar::foo(int, int)' is not declared in '::'
```

We have confirmed that this is an error in gcc 4.8, 4.4 and clang 3.7 however it appears to work with Visual Studio 2015.

We ran into this problem when we tried to instantiate `std::remove` but had `<algorithm>` included before `<cstdio>` and `<cstdio>` has in it

```
namespace std {
   using ::remove;
}
```

Any ideas on whats going on here?

Comment: Is there a requirement to use the above listed compiler versions? If not, you can evaluate the above listed code at https://godbolt.org and use the different compilers to see the code generated.

Comment: Your posted code is not exactly analogous to `std::remove` from `cstdio` and `algorithm`. If you add `int foo(int)` to `bar` to start with, there seems to be no problem at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/40xVXX).

Comment: The question remains: is the above code legal? If so, then we identified a bug in gcc.  If not, then there is an issue with the standard.

Comment: I've tried g++ 6.3 and clang++ 3.8, and both compile the example without error, so I would guess that there are bugs in the old compilers you used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is related to [an ancient bug in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56480), where you cannot explicitly instantiate a template by using `ns::func`, the only way was to do it using `namespace ns { ... func; }`. This was only recently fixed and with [newer gcc your code will compile](https://godbolt.org/g/Y2xDhX).

And by the way, contrary to what you are saying, your code [compiles with clang 3.7](https://godbolt.org/g/zm1LTz).

Comment: Can you tell me where a specialization is being forward declared?  Are explicit instantiations considered specializations?

Comment: @jlehrer Yes, you are correct. That bug in gcc though had lots of issues related to that kind of `ns::func` wording